Namespace for jQuery plugin
I have a jQuery plugin I created for my needs. Now all functions are in global namespace which isn't good, I would like to move them to hoo.account namespace.
Here how my code looks right now:
(($) => {
    $.fn.toggleActive = function(active) {
        this.toggleClass("active", active);
        this.children(".data__form-activator").toggle(!active);
        this.children(".data__form-btn").toggleClass("visible", active);
        this.children(".data__flex-row").toggleClass("_m-none", !active);
        this.find("input, select").prop("disabled", !active);

        return this;
    };

    $.fn.activate = function() {
        return this.toggleActive(true);
    };

    $.fn.deactivate = function() {
        return this.toggleActive(false);
    };
})(jQuery);

Now I'm calling $(...).activate(), but I wanna call it $(...).hoo.account.activate().
Thanks in advance!

$(...)hoo isn't valid syntax

@Bravo, thanks, mistyped, I corrected message.

this looks like a huge headache in the future
